# Passing a set of parameters to a program using a Bash variable

Tags: bash, shell, array

I'm trying to clean up my shell script by placing repeating parameters in a bash variable.

The best approach I know is to put it in an array and pass it... but that doesn't seem to work. How can I store all the parameters in a variable?

This doesn't work:

```
TESTP=( "-path" "\"./var/*\"")
echo ${TESTP[@]}
 # Results in: -path "./var/*"
find ${TESTP[@]}
 # Returns no results.
```

While `find -path "./var/*"` does return all files under var.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You either want to pass those array elements as arguments to `find`:

```
TESTP=(-path './var/*')
find . "${TESTP[@]}"
```

Or build a *shell* command line and ask the shell to interpret it (and the quotes in it):

```
TESTP='-path "./var/*"'
eval "find . $TESTP"
```

Or you could use the split+glob operator (which you inappropriately used by leaving your variable unquoted in your question) on a scalar variable:

```
TESTP='-path,./var/*'

set -f # no glob
IFS=,  # split on ,
find . $TESTP
```

In your,

```
TESTP=( "-path" "\"./var/*\"")
find ${TESTP[@]}
```

`${TESTP[@]}` is first expanded to the array element (`-path` and `"./var/*"`), and then each is subject to the split+glob operator (as you forgot to quote it), so with the default value of `$IFS`, they would not be split, but because the second one contains a wildcard it could be expanded to the files whose name end in `"` in the `"./var` directory.

Most likely there's no `".` directory, so both arguments are left asis and passed to `find`. And that would be the same as

```
find -path '"./var/*"'
```

That is, looking for files below the `"./var` directory that end in a `"` character.