# Dynamically generated parameters Not given to tool

Tags: bash

I would like to call a tool via command line. I need to generate the parameters to be used for calling dynamically. Furthermore there is a number of parameters which needs to be given to the tool.

```
COMMAND=""
for i in $VERSIONS; do
    COMMAND+=" '../apache-maven-$i/bin/mvn clean'"
done
```

So now I want to call the tool with the generated list of parameters (from above) like this:

```
hyperfine --export-markdown ../results.md -w 5 $COMMAND
```

But unfortunately that produces the following result:

```
Benchmark #1: '../apache-maven-3.0.5/bin/mvn
Error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code. Use the '-i'/'--ignore-failure'
     option if you want to ignore this. Alternatively, 
use the '--show-output' option to debug what went wrong.
```

My assumption is that the created parameters `$COMMAND` is not identified as multiple parameters. It's taken as a single parameter which is wrong. If I printout the whole command line and copy that into the bash line manually the execution works perfectly.

```
hyperfine --export-markdown ../results.md -w 5 '~/tools/apache-maven-3.8.2/bin/mvn clean' '~/tools/apache-maven-3.8.1/bin/mvn clean' '~/tools/apache-maven-4.0.0-alpha-1-SNAPSHOT/bin/mvn clean'
```

Is there something special to be taken into account while generating multiple parameters for calling other tools in Bash?

Comment: Does [Passing a set of parameters to a program using a Bash variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241863/passing-a-set-of-parameters-to-a-program-using-a-bash-variable) answer your question?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Unfortunately it does not.. But thanks for your help.

Comment: See also [Conditionally pass params to a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/446847/170373) and [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/170373). Note the single quote in the message you get: `Benchmark #1: '../apache-maven-3.0.5/bin/mvn`; hyperfine probably tries to run that as a command, with the single quote and all. Perhaps the `--show-output` option would clarify that.

Comment: Your situation seems basically the same as in those linked questions, just that you're not passing a single command in multiple arguments, but multiple strings that are command lines themselves. (If I got it right what hyperfine does.) In any case, they're arguments strings that contain whitespace, which triggers the problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue here is that the single quotes are becoming part of the commands you want to benchmark with `hyperfine`.

Instead, we suppose you want to collect all the commands in an array and then use that.

```bsh
commands=()
for version in "${versions[@]}"; do
    commands+=( "../apache-maven-$version/bin/mvn clean" )
done

hyperfine --warmup 5 --export-markdown ../results.md "${commands[@]}"
```

In the code above, I'm assuming that `versions` is an array, like

```bsh
versions=( '3.8.1' '3.8.2' '4.0.0-alpha-1-SNAPSHOT' )
```

The expansion of `"${commands[@]}"` will be the commands that you want to benchmark, each individually quoted.

However, `hyperfine` can use your `versions` array directly.

```bsh
(
        IFS=,
        hyperfine               \
                --warmup 5      \
                --export-markdown ../results.md                 \
                --parameter-list version "${versions[*]}"       \
                '../apache-maven-{version}/bin/mvn clean'
)
```

or, if you prefer short options and long one-liners,

```bsh
( IFS=, ; hyperfine -w 5 --export-markdown ../results.md -L version "${versions[*]}" '../apache-maven-{version}/bin/mvn clean' )
```

Again, this assumes that `versions` is an array like what we showed above.  Setting `IFS` to a comma makes `"${versions[*]}"` expand to a comma-delimited string of version strings. Doing this in a subshell avoids modifying `IFS` in the calling shell.

When you use a comma-delimited string with `--parameter-list placeholder`, any occurrence of the string `{placeholder}` in the command string given as the operand is replaced by the elements of that string in turn.